# ng-model for <select> is not setting the selected value in angular dart while using <option>

Tags: angularjs, angular-dart

`ng-model`, not working on `select` only in directive

```
<select ng-model="employees.employee"  required="true">
<option id="employee_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="employee in employees" value="{{employee.name}}">{{employee.name}}</option>
</select>
```

while loading the form, Default selected value is not set in the dropdown.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't use ng-options instead.  I find it easier to work with in a directive

Comment: Also, it's odd that your collection for ng-repeat is employees and that your ng-model is a property named employee on employees.  My guess is that one or the other of those is incorrect?

Comment: how you are assigning the value? I have faced the same issue in my application where I am passing value to $scope  eg $scope.employees.employee = ''somevalue". instead pass $scope.employees.employee ={name: 'somevalue'}

Comment: What version are you using, AngularJs ? angular.dart ? Angular2 Dart ?

Comment: Am using Angular Dart VM version: 1.15.0